# Is there a way to make a Regex function to check a first and last name?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm currently doing an assignment for my coding class (I'm a beginner). The assignment is to create an HTML page with 2 inputs, one for a First Name, one for a Last Name, and to make a submit button that, when clicked, checks to see if the First and Last Names both start with an uppercase letter and contain at least 1 character. When they both match the regex, an alert is used and the console logs. When they don't, a different alert is used, and the console doesn't log. When I finished making the html and the script, I typed in a name in both inputs that should match the regex, but it only issues an alert for an incorrect input. There is something wrong, but I can't find it.

```
function regexChecker(firstName, lastName) {
    firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").innerHTML;
    lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").innerHTML;
    let firstNameRegex = /^[A-Z][a-z]*$/;
    let lastNameRegex = /^[A-Z][a-z]*$/;
    if (firstName.match(firstNameRegex) && lastName.match(lastNameRegex)) {
        alert('Yay! Your inputs were all correct!' );
        console.log(true);
    }
    else {
        alert('Oh no! Thats an invalid format!' );
        console.log(false);
    }
}
```

In the linked html that I didn't provide, there are two inputs for each name, as well as a button. I inputted the name Isaac in the first one and Daniels in the second.
I expected the alert to be "Yay! Your inputs were all correct!", but I instead got "Oh no! Thats an invalid format!"

Comment: innerHTML is not for inputs

Comment: This works: `/^([A-Z][a-z]*)+$/`

Comment: This is OK for an assignment but do note that people have names like O'Neil (with a ') and Björk. Don't make this mistake with actual production code. Further reading: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making two mistakes:

- Use `value` instead of `innerHTML`. `<input>` doesnot have `innerHTML`
- `match` returns an array which is always truthy. Even `Boolean([]) => true`. You should use `test()` instead of `match`.
- Your `RegExp` will not pass a string containing capital letter after first. You should use `/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$/`

Here is the code.

```
function regexChecker(firstName, lastName) {
    firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    let firstNameRegex = /^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$/;
    let lastNameRegex = /^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$/;
    if (firstNameRegex.test(firstName) && lastNameRegex.test(lastName)) {
        alert('Yay! Your inputs were all correct!' );
        console.log(true);
    }
    else {
        alert('Oh no! Thats an invalid format!' );
        console.log(false);
    }
}
```

**Note**:Both the strings have same regex `/^[A-Z][a-z]*$/` so you could use `every()` to check on both.

```
function regexChecker(firstName, lastName) {
    firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    let regex = /^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$/;
    if ([firstName,lastName].every(x => regex.test(x))) {
        alert('Yay! Your inputs were all correct!' );
        console.log(true);
    }
    else {
        alert('Oh no! Thats an invalid format!' );
        console.log(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: There’s also no need to use innerHTML. You can just use value for an input text box. You can also make the regex pattern one variable since they’re identical.

Comment: match is truthy so it would be fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regexp:

```
/^([A-Z][a-z]*)+$/
```

It will test that it starts with an uppercase letter, and is followed by lower case letters, and is at least one letter long.

You can use the regexp with `.test()` to get a true/false value.

```js
let regexp = /^([A-Z][a-z]*)+$/

document.names.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  let firstValid = regexp.test(document.names.first.value)
  let lastValid = regexp.test(document.names.last.value)
  
  // Sanity check
  console.log(firstValid, lastValid)
  
  if (!firstValid) alert('First name is invalid!')
  else if (!lastValid) alert('Last name is invalid!')
  else alert('Both are valid!')
})
```

```html
<form name="names">
  <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="First Name">
  <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Last Name">
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Check Names">
  </p>
</form>
```